# C# Получение коллекций с вложенными коллекциями из базы MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, observablecollection

Здравствуйте! 
Вопрос такой - в своём приложении использую, например, класс подразделения (Department), у которого есть вложенная коллекция сотрудников (Employee).

Задача - получить коллекцию всех подразделений с сотрудниками.

Подразделений много, сотрудников очень много, и в итоге эта конструкция работает довольно долго...

Упрощенно выглядит так:

```
public class Department
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees {get;set;}

    public static ObservableCollection<Department> GetAll()
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         ObservableCollection<Department> Deps = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
         using (SqlConnection conn = DBHelper.CreateConnection())
         {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Departments_GetAll]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
         }

         foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
         {
            Department dep = new Department{
                 ID = row["ID"].ToString(),
                 Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                 Employees = Employee.GetByDepartmentID(row["ID"].ToString())
            };
            Deps.Add(dep);
         }
         return Departments;
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    public static ObservableCollection<Employee> GetByDepartmentID (string departmentID)
    {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
         using (SqlConnection conn = DBHelper.CreateConnection())
         {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[Employees_GetByDepartmentID]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DepID", new Guid(departmentID)));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
         }

         foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
         {
              Employee emp = new Employee
              {
                   ID = row["ID"].ToString(),
                   FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
                   LastName = row["LastName"].ToString()
              };
              Employees.Add(emp);
         }
         return Employees;
    }
}
```

Это один из примеров, схема очень упрощенная. Свойств, естественно, больше. Вложенные коллекции могут уходить и на пять уровней вглубь. Работает это всё очень неповоротливо (сами sql запросы очень быстро, медленно именно на уровне объектной модели). Подтащить все коллекции заранее и работать по ним через linq - не вариант, т.к. их много, и в базе всё динамически меняется, локальные данные будут сразу устаревать (или их надо как-то не затратно обновлять, не не знаю как).

Являюсь самоучкой, чую что делаю что-то в корне неправильно... Подскажите, как работать с получением вложенных коллекций чтобы не было мучительно больно...

Заранее большое спасибо за советы.

Comment: Вы уверены что тормозит именно объектная модель? Тут очевидная проблема в количество запросов. Вам надо загрузить всех связанных сотрудников одним запросом, после чего спокойно "раскидать" их по отделам.

Comment: @PavelMayorov В данном случае я привел пример, когда нужно получить все отделы, со всеми сотрудниками. Но чаще необходимо получить один конкретный отдел и его сотрудников. При общем количестве сотрудников около 2500, и численности одного отдела около 100 - мне кажется что получение всех 2500 будет неоправданно. Но спасибо за совет, попробую подумать в этом направлении.

Comment: Так я потому и пишу: надо загружать связанных сотрудников, а не всех. Но одним запросом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Тогда возможно я неправильно вас понял. Но дело в том, что в моём примере в методе Employee.GetByDepartmentID как раз и подгружаются связанные сотрудники, у которых значение ParentDepartmentID == ID подразделения (в хранимой процедуре). Получаем заполненный DataTable со связанными сотрудниками и проходим по нему циклом, создавая экземпляры класса Employee и добавляя в коллекцию.

Comment: Вы при этом делаете столько запросов, сколько у вас отделов. А надо - 1 раз.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону EntityFramework (либо любой другой ORM). Данный подход позволит вам незатратно обновлять модель Ваших данных, при этом указать только те таблицы, которые вам интересны.

Поскольку БД уже иемеется, то модель генерации Database First.
Обратить внимание стоит на модель загрузки вложенных коллекций (Lazy Loading, Eager Loading).

После генерации модели, если у указаны все связи в СУБД, получите набор прокси-классов, которые будут предоставлять доступ к сущностям вашей БД. 
Обращаться к связанным сущностям можно будет через Navigation Properties. И, в зависимости от выбранной модели загрузки будет формироваться либо отдельный запрос, либо все данные (к которым обращаетесь в этом запросе) будут подгружаться одним запросом.